# Tax logics and setup settings

Tags: magento2, tax, tax-class, tax-calculation

I'm using Magento 2. I have updated the products price including Tax value. I want to show all product price value with included tax at the cart page.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can change settings to display price including Tax on cart page

> Admin->Stores->Configuration->Sales->Tax->Shopping Cart Display
>   Settings

Comment: How do i show 20% tax at checkout page with product original price? Means we not adding extra 20% to the product price but we should show 20% including tax.